# How to avoid adding an undefined key that won't be accessed because of an early return in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, javascript-objects, optional-parameters

I'm looking for a way to write a function where I don't have to include a key with undefined value in TypeScript. Partly for stylistic reasons and partly because I feel like I may be misunderstanding something or missing a more defensive way to write it.

In the function I potentially access an object using a key that's one of the arguments. If the optional argument has a specific key, there's an early return with no accessing involved.

```js
type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

function foo(type: MyType, objectArgument?: Record<string, number>) {
  if (type === 'baz' && objectArgument?.someProperty) {
    return {
      someKey: `hello ${someComputation(objectArgument.someProperty)}`,
      anotherKey: `goodbye ${someComputation(objectArgument.someProperty)}`
    }
  }

  const opts = {
    foo: {
      x: 'some string'
    },
    bar: {
      y: 'another string'
    }
    baz: undefined // without this baz the error the compiler errors with:
    // `Property 'baz' does not exist on type '{ foo: { x: string; }; bar: { y: string; }; }`
  }

  return opts[type]
}
```

some example invocations:

```
foo('foo')
foo('bar')
foo('baz', { someProperty: 123 })
```

In the example above, is there a way that I can write the `opts` object without the `baz: undefined` kvp?

I've tried wrapping the second `opts` obj in an if statement (the remaining two types) and also successfully silenced the error by using `return opts[type as keyof typeof opts]` but after reading up on `as keyof typeof` notation in other questions I'm not sure I understand it and want to make sure I haven't just tricked the compiler erroneously.

**Edit:**

As someone pointed out, the compiler was indeed correct in warning me of this. If someone invoked the `foo('baz')` with no second argument, then the `opts` object would still be accessed with the key, which doesn't exist.

Rewrote this with an `||` and default value if the second argument wasn't present:

```
function foo(type: MyType, objectArgument?: Record<string, number>) {
  const opts = {
    foo: {
      x: 'some string'
    },
    bar: {
      y: 'another string'
    }
    baz: { 
     someKey: `hello ${objectArugment.someProperty || 'some default value'}}`
  }

  return opts[type]
}
```

Comment: This creating a object just to return one property of it pretty strange. Are you open to alternatives? https://tsplay.dev/we6xEN

Comment: If `objectArgument?.someProperty` can be falsy, that means that your `if`, the type can technically still be `baz`. So it's not a guaranteed early return. Consequently, `opts[type]` needs to handle that case.

Comment: Well the TypeScript compiler is right - one could invoke `foo('baz')` (or `foo('baz', { someProperty: 0 })`) and `opts.baz` would be accessed. So indeed you do need it.

Comment: @qrsngky @Bergi ah, y'all are right, for that first case I was only ever invoking it with the two arguments `foo('baz', { someProperty: 123 })` — have edited the question with the solution I ended up going with. Thanks!

Comment: If `someProperty` can be `0` or `""`, the `||` may not be what you're looking for. The `??` operator was designed for this purpose.

Comment: @qrsngky I always forget about `??` so thanks for reminding, but I've tested this with someProperty being both `0` and `''` and `'some default value'` is still correctly interpolated. Indeed using `??` makes there be no value interpolated at all. It does work with `someProperty: null`, but so does `||`.

Comment: @saylestyler Use `||` if you really want `hello some default value` when `0` or `""` is provided. If you want `hello 0` when `0` is provided, and `hello ` when `""` is provided, then use  `??`.

Comment: @qrsngky gotcha ya I wanted the `some default value` : ) but thank you for reminding me about ms `??`

Answer (score -2):

In TypeScript keyword `Exclude` can help you

```js
type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

function someComputation(n: number) { return n*2; }

function foo(type: MyType, objectArgument?: Record<string, number>) {
  if (type === 'baz' && objectArgument?.someProperty) {
    return {
      someKey: `hello ${someComputation(objectArgument.someProperty)}`,
      anotherKey: `goodbye ${someComputation(objectArgument.someProperty)}`
    }
  }

  const opts = {
    foo: {
      x: 'some string'
    },
    bar: {
      y: 'another string'
    },
  }

  return opts[type as Exclude<MyType,'baz'>]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve any compiler error and also is not advisable in light of the fact that if `.someProperty` is undefined `baz` could still be accessed, but thanks for reminding about the ever handy `Exclude`